# Aws-cli brew update warning , not sure how to fix it

Tags: amazon-web-services, homebrew, aws-cli, homebrew-cask

Whenever I try to run `brew update` I am getting this warning. I am not sure how to fix it as it's related to `aws-cli`.

```
Warning: Some installed kegs have no formulae!
This means they were either deleted or installed manually.
You should find replacements for the following formulae:
  pycparser
```

I Tried reinstalling the brew package for `aws-cli` after uninstalling it.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this its an issue with homebrew i used `brew untap homebrew/core` and the issue got fixed

Answer (score 0):

On my machine I had the following warnings from `brew doctor`:

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: Some installed kegs have no formulae!
This means they were either deleted or installed manually.
You should find replacements for the following formulae:
  pycparser
  cffi

Warning: You have an unnecessary local Cask tap.
This can cause problems installing up-to-date casks.
Please remove it by running:
  brew untap homebrew/cask

Warning: You have an unnecessary local Core tap!
This can cause problems installing up-to-date formulae.
Please remove it by running:
 brew untap homebrew/core
```

After running both

```
brew untap homebrew/cask
```

and

```
brew untap homebrew/core
```

resolved the issue:

```
brew update && brew upgrade && brew autoremove && brew doctor
Already up-to-date.
Your system is ready to brew.
```